# how to redirect previous page after alert in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I want to display alerts succeed then after click ok, then it will be redirected to the previous page. 
from my code below, where were his fault or deficiency? 
  because of my following code, when clicking ok does not redirect the page to the previous page.

This is my code :

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Surat berhasil di Approve')</script>");
string prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
Response.Write("<script>location.href='" + prevPage + "'</script>");
```

Comment: It works fine over here, do you have any javascript errors in your console?

Comment: Add some more tags so people know what you're talking about. From what you've posted I don't know if you're talking about Asp.Net or something else.

Comment: maybe use history.back()?

Comment: @user2538170 Please click [edit] and add tags there to indicate that. Thanks :)